# Switch BottomNavigationDrawer fragments on button click

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I created an android app and chose `BottomNavigationDrawer` template for the `MainActivity`. Android Studio generated all the code for me which is nice but I have placed a button in one of my `fragments` and I want to navigate to another `fragment` when user clicks that `button`. I did something like this on button click:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment(), fragment.toString());
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
```

This is my `activity_main.xml` which is generated by Android Studio:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

All my other fragments are in the `navigation` folder inside `res` folder and again, this is done by Android Studio by default. The `id` that I am passing in the `replace` above is the culprit and I don't know which `id` should I pass here.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more detail for better help. However, put this **setReorderingAllowed** before **commit** the Home fragment.